# Solar Panel Collector type for Caribbean

Tags: water-heater, solar-panels

I live in the Caribbean and am looking to get a solar water heater system. I’m looking into flat panel or evacuated tube system. I got an offer for an evacuated tube system with a stainless steel tank for a descent price. I have a 2 floor concrete house with a flat roof and no trees nearby. i have 2.5 bathrooms. At the moment we are just 2. Given my location, would the evacuated system be better? What should look for?

I got offered this ET system with installation for $1,300 plus tax.

[image]
[image]

It includes a 120 gallon stainless steel tank.Flat panel systems with a regular 82 gallon tank (non stainless steel) run for the same price.

Comment: Are the heat outputs of the two systems the same? In the USA that is measured in BTU/day.

Comment: Ask the guy in your area who is selling flat plate collectors.  In general ET collectors are for locations that are very cold or often cloudy.

Comment: @chris Your comment makes sense to me; you'd want to use evacuated tubes when you needed to reduce heat loss in a cold environment.